# Huge white gap in header when slimming page to mobile view

Tags: html, css

If you go to this page (https://www.comparestonehengetours.com/) in Mobile or Tablet View the logo has loads of white space on top of it. Is there any way to remove all the white space so it just shows the logo nicely?

I have attached an image to help explain better what I mean.

Thanks, Chris
[image: Mobile View]

Answer (score 4):

You should learn to use inspect element in Chrome.

[image]

If you do, you can use the pointer to select the element and track down the padding.

[image]

You can see if you make the first two values of padding and margin 0 it will dissappear.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you override these rules setting the *padding* and *margin*, you should have it:

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) and (min-width: 450px)
 #mj-header {
     /* padding: 55px 0 0px; */
 }

@media screen and (max-width: 700px)
#mj-header {
    /* padding: 55px 0 0; */
    /* margin: 55px 0 0; */
}
```

P.S. it is not good to post links of live sites. Better try to post just a sample of the problem, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the huge padding on top when your screen shrinks. Its inside the CSS.

Remove:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 720px) {
  #mj-header {
    padding: 25px 0 5px;
  }
}
```

Or make it:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 720px) {
  #mj-header {
    padding: 5px 0;
  }
}
```

from your CSS.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

a quick fix would be to put a media query ( in this case standard iphone)

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}
```

and adjust the padding and margins accordingly ( the 55px add up to 110 white gap up top.

hope this helps!